# How to use regex in XPath "contains" function

Tags: regex, xpath, selenium-webdriver, contains

I would like to match the following text `sometext12345_text` using the below regex.

I'm using this in one of my selenium tests.

```
String expr = "//*[contains(@id, 'sometext[0-9]+_text')]";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(expr));
```

It doesn't seem to work though. Can somebody help?

Comment: What version of XPath are you using?

Comment: What made you think it might work? Were you just guessing, or did you find misleading information somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelKay, I guessed that it might support. As per this, (http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#string.match) it may not. Thanks.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

XPath 1.0 doesn't handle regex natively, you could try something like

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'sometext') and ends-with(@id, '_text')]
```

(as pointed out by paul t, `//*[boolean(number(substring-before(substring-after(@id, "sometext"), "_text")))]` could be used to perform the same check your original regex does, if you need to check for middle digits as well)

In XPath 2.0, try

```
//*[matches(@id, 'sometext\d+_text')]
```

Comment: This seems to work: `//*[boolean(number(substring-before(substring-after(@id, "sometext"), "_text")))]`, but it's highly specific to this use case

Comment: Yup, regex support would obviously be stronger/more flexible. Nice trick though!

Comment: seems like 'ends-with()' comes only with XPath2/XQuery but not with XPath1.0, proofs: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions , http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with

Comment: How do I get to know which version of xpath is bein used in my selenium test?

Comment: @Robin - could you please help me with a related question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292671/how-to-search-for-exact-text-using-xpath-and-regex

Comment: couldn't use ends-with in xpath 1.0,
but starts-with works perfectly :)

Answer (score 13):

In Robins's answer ends-with is not supported in xpath 1.0 too.. Only starts-with is supported...
So if your condition is not very specific..You can Use like this which worked for me

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'sometext') and contains(@name,'_text')]`\
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Selenium with Firefox you should be able to use [EXSLT extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/EXSLT), and [regexp:test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/EXSLT/regexp/test)

Does this work for you?

```
String expr = "//*[regexp:test(@id, 'sometext[0-9]+_text')]";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(expr));
```

Comment: I'm using webdriver(2.39.0) with firefox(26.0). I tried the above suggestion but it results in error. `InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[regexp:test(@id, 'sometext[0-9]+_text')] because of the following error:
[Exception... "An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces"  code: "14" nsresult: "0x8053000e (NamespaceError)"  location: "<unknown>"]`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium, but if you find a way to register the namespace `"http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"` under the `"regexp"` prefix, it could work

Comment: Looks like the issue is still open for registering namespaces (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1694), and it's independent of the EXSLT extensions. There are signs of people doing it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130149/2572383 ... Ah no, I think the parsing there is done outside

Comment: @paultrmbrth -  - could you please help me with a related question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292671/how-to-search-for-exact-text-using-xpath-and-regex