# How to select dynamic checkbox using AngularJS in selenium webdriver?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

All checkbox are dynamic in the application.

I need to select the checkbox either single or mulitple checkbox. xpath is given below..

//*[@id='abs5a1164da']/div[1]/div

Along with abs, there is dynamic value is coming. it is dynamic it fails.. How to use as generic to make it work on all attempt.instead of contain, is it possible to use any reg expression to fulfil this??

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/xpath-using-regex-in-contains-function
It might solve your problem.

Comment: that did not have what i wanted

Comment: what is ur html source?