# How to search for exact text using xpath and regex?

Tags: html, regex, xpath

An html paragraph contains the text Join {text} Now, or Join {text} Today. The xpath locator I created for this does not work. How do I make it work ?

```
//p[matches(text(), 'Join.*/^Today$/|/^Now$/')]
```

Answer (score -1):

I created one on the http://regexr.com/. Is stayed like this: `\bJoin.*(\bToday|\bNow)`. Try it.