# Identify table row and table data - CSS Selector Python

Tags: python, selenium, html-table, css-selectors

I have multiple cases of table rows from which I want to extract data:

Case 1

```
 Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis  April 19, 2014  April 19, 2017
```

Case 2

```
CAR                                     October 15, 2016    October 15, 2017    
Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis   October 15, 2016    October 15, 2019
```

Case 3

```
NBD ProSupport                          July 16, 2008   July 15, 2011   
Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis   July 16, 2008   July 15, 2011
```

The information that I need to be extracted is on the rows that contain "Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis" on the second td, which will be for every case the date on the right of the row

Expected output:

```
                      April 19, 2017
                    October 15, 2017
                       July 15, 2011
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from openpyxl import load_workbook

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


def scrape(codes):
    dates = []
    for i in range(len(codes)):
        driver.get("https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/"
                   "servicetag/%s/warranty?ref=captchasuccess" % codes[i])

    # Solve captcha manually
        if i == 0:
            print("You now have 120\" seconds to solve the captcha")
            time.sleep(120)
            print("120\" Passed")
    # Extract data
        expdate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#printdivid > div > div.not-annotated.hover > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)")
        print(expdate.get_attribute('innerText'))
    driver.close()

codes = ['159DT3J', '15FDBG2', '10V8YZ1']
scrape(codes)
```

My output:

```
April 19, 2014
October 15, 2016
July 16, 2008
```

Taken from the first row that appears and the first `td`
I've tried changing `tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)`but identifying based on the text would be better and avoid errors.

Comment: Please give the HTML code of table includes above example datas

Comment: @Jewlanu Are you looking to extract the text for `Warranty expiration date` for the first item of all the three pages?

Comment: @yong I have managed to solve the problem, thank you for your time!

Comment: @New contributor, yes, that is what I want to extract, but I managed to solve it :) hope it will work for all my tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to extract text for "Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis", I would suggest you update the line you are using for finding the element with the following:

```
expdate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis']/following-sibling::td")
```

Here, we are using xpath locator and looking for `td` alongside text '*Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis*'

Comment: Is there any way to go to the next td? as there are two of them and the seconds is the one that I am looking for

Comment: Yes, just add an index to the xpath `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//td[text()='Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis']/following-sibling::td)[2]")`

Comment: I added the index like this "//td[text()='Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis']/following-sibling::td[2]") and it works :)

Comment: Done. Quick question...could a regex be used for the text? Would that work?

Comment: You may read this thread for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/xpath-using-regex-in-contains-function