# Selenium. Xpath. Find element by array of words

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Currently I need to find elements, that have at least one or more words from some array.

Here is the code that I have:

```
collect(['some', 'words'])->each(function ($word) {
    $found = $this->driver->findElements(
        WebDriverBy::xpath("//div[contains(text(), '$word')]")
    );
});
```

Is is possible somehow to make it using one `findElements()` call and pass the array there?

Comment: You could try building a regex? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/xpath-using-regex-in-contains-function

Comment: @lucaswxp my array does not have any pattern, so this may be quite unpleasant and hard to read afterwards.

Comment: I don't understand. A simple join will do, you want the final output "(word1|word2|word3)"

Comment: The number of words is different each time or hardcoded words?

Comment: @lucaswxp Could you show an example?

Comment: @Andersson hardcoded

Comment: If there are couple words by which you need to find element, you can try `"//div[contains(text(), 'some') and contains(text(), 'words')]"`

Comment: @D.R. Would you be able to port it to Php if I answer in Java?

Comment: You just need to use an XPath that consists of a bunch of OR conditions for each word in your collection of words. If you google, you will see some examples of how to use OR in XPath. Once you try that, update your question with the results if it doesn't work.