# How to use regex for XPath attribute definition

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath

I have a DOM element with the following unique attribute

```
ui-sref=".carts.cart({type:'agent'})"
```

so I need to define a XPath for Selenium to find this element.

I can use

```
//li[contains(@ui-sref,"carts") and contains(@ui-sref,"agent")]
```

and it works fine.

Can I use something like

```
//li[contains(@ui-sref,"carts"*"agent")
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/xpath-using-regex-in-contains-function

Comment: Without Xpath, any element: `<[\w:]+(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sui-sref\s*=\s*(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?carts(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?agent(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`