# Scrapy - xpath with a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I'm **scraping** a page with some divs with the id = Content_Main_ some random number but can't get their content using the following xpath because the result is always empty, what I'm doing wrong?

`//div[re:test(@id, '([Content_Main_]+\d{5}[0-9])')]`

```
/div[@id='Content_Main_4']
/div[@id='Content_Main_5']
/div[@id='Content_Main_8']
```

Comment: can you share your input xml?

Comment: This should help..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/xpath-using-regex-in-contains-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like (starting with `Content_Main_` and next a `digit`):

```
//div[re:test(@id, 'Content_Main_\d+')]
```

**UPDATE**
To select `div`s ending with a number you need:

```
//div[re:test(@id, 'Content_Main_\d+$')]
```

Comment: I think I'm almost there, now the response is not empty but some divs I don't need are coming too, how can I change the expression to ignore divs like I'd = Content_Main_31_userControl_lbl_title and get only the  ones who start with Content_Main_ and ends right after the number (Content_Main_4, Content_Main_5, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching exactly five digits after

```
text(Content_Main_)
\d{5}
```

- Search 5 digits example : 12345; 76543....

make it like:

```
\d -- if it is always one digit
or
\d+ - if it can have one or more digit
or
\d* - if it may/may not have digit
```