# Using the OR logical function in the "starts with" condition for finding the xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I use the following X-path to extract a web element based on the starts-with condition

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'https://test-abc-eu.softcore.com')]
```

I want to increase the scope of the search by adding a logical OR condition to the search. Anything that starts with

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'https://test-abc-eu.softcore.com')]
//a[starts-with(@href,'https://test-abc.softcore.com')]
```

Something like

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'https://test-abc-eu.softcore.com' or @href,'https://test-abc.softcore.com')]
```

Is this possible?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Because your requirements are similar, would you mind looking at the answer to this question and see if it addresses your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/xpath-using-regex-in-contains-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'http://test-abc.softcore.com') or starts-with(@href,'https://test-abc-eu.softcore.com')]
```

Demo:

[image]

As you can see both links are matched.

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)